# Request for member `type' in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, pointers, struct

When Compiled I get the error:

request for member `type' in something not a structure or union,

this error is happening when the strcmp() function is used on a passed char array and pointer to struct.

What I am trying to do is pass in a 'string' and have it return the index in the array where the 'string' is located.

```
int returnDuplicate(char word , struct data *value)
{

int i = 0;
int placefinder = -60;

for (i ; i <= 50 ; i++)
{

  if ( strcmp(word, value.type[i]) == 0)
     {
       placefinder = i;

     }
}

return placefinder;
}




struct data {
             char type[50][16];
             double whole[50];
             double retail[50];
             double profit[50];
          };
```

Comment: And every answer below that says "use `value->type[i]`" should footnote you can also use `(*value).type[i]`. The first of these two forms (`->`) is there to provide you with the ability to perform the second form (`(*var).`) with two-fewer characters to type; and yes, that really *is* the reason. That and paren-hell is averted (I sometimes think K&R were [Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language))-haters).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two problems that I see:

1. You want to be using `char*` as the type of your `word` parameter, if you want it to be a (C) string. Not `char`.

   `int returnDuplicate(char* word , struct data *value)`
2. `value` is a pointer to a `struct data`. Therefore, you have to use the `->` operator, not `.` to access its members.

   `strcmp(word, value->type[i])`

Answer (score 4):

In this line:

```
if ( strcmp(word, value.type[i]) == 0)
```

You are trying to access the `type` field of `value`, but `value` is a pointer to a `struct`, not a `struct` itself.  Try changing that line to

```
 if ( strcmp(word, value->type[i]) == 0)
```

The error that you're getting is the canonical "you used `.` instead of `->`" error from `gcc`.  Once you've seen it enough times, you get a feel for what it means.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

As you are passing `value` as pointer to a struct, so you need to use `->` operator to access struct's fields instead of `.`:

```
if ( strcmp(word, value->type[i]) == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a * in the prototype:  `char * word`